# Этимология отмазка

Tags: этимология

Отмазка на сленге означает "оправдание".  Единственное что я нашёл, что маз это "возможность, вероятность".

Заранее благодарствую!

Comment: In My Humble Opinion  Отмазка  (неофиц.)  — способ отмазаться от чего-либо неприятного.  МАЗАТЬ. (сов. намазать) перех. Покрывать слоем чего-л. жидкого или жирного.  Это чтобы было легче выскользнуть/ускользнуть.  Также МАЗА  https://otvet.mail.ru/question/7327542